# How can I get more expedition modules?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

I found some ruins with my explorer and let it dig around a bit. But when I went with this explorer to a second site, I couldn't construct an expedition there.

I checked the Civilopedia and it said that expeditions consume expedition modules, and I noticed that my explorer didn't have any expedition modules left.

[image]

How can I get more expedition modules, so I simply have to built more explorers, or can I get them in any other way?

Comment: Is anyone else finding it a little ironic that Sid Meier is asking questions about his own game? ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Send your explorer back into one of your cities to gain another expedition module.  It's similar to the way units in Civ5 have to go back to your territory to upgrade.

Additionally, there's a Virtue called *Pathfinders* in Tier II of the Prosperity tree that will give your explorers 3 more expedition modules. Upon choosing this virtue, all your explorers will instantly receive 3 more modules regardless of their location.

Comment: Yup. The tutorial points this out.

Comment: Except it's impossible to return into your city : when ordering the explorer to move into it, the hexagon is red.
Just putting the explorer in a hex used by the city doesn't seems to be enough. How does getting extra module works ????

Comment: If you can't enter the city, check for idle units in the city hex.

Comment: You can't stack military units into the same hex.  A lot of the same game concepts from Civ5 have carried over to this game.

Comment: It took me an entire game before I realized my explorers could refill their modules.  I kept making new ones whenever I wanted to excavate again >.<  What a waste!  Then I had one go auto-explore and was confused when I saw him excavating a second time.